# How is this logic of moderation conducive to a growing learning environment?

Tags: discussion

**How is this logic of moderation conducive to a growing learning environment (in the context that Meta is a general platform for building Stack Exchange as opposed to asking for help in another community)?**

- Downvoting because a question was previously asked
- Downvoting because of incorrect grammar, punctuation, typo, etc. (as some are not native-English speakers.)
- Downvoting for not formatting
- Any of these upvoted for the same/opposite reason

None of these reasons adequately vote on the **policy/feature** in question. It only addresses the questions structure which is why moderators have a hold/merge/duplicate option.

**Why are we voting on Meta in the first place, the policy or the condition of the question?**

Is it because we like/dislike a policy/feature or because we like/dislike the capitalization (in short).

THIS question is not about the downvoting policy. This is about alternative ways to moderate a voting policy. I only added this as an example:

My experience is that actual questions are avoided being answered in lieu of being downvoted purely because of a duplicate. If a user doesn't have enough reputation points he/she can not cast a vote for a policy he/she agrees with thus his/her only way to 'vote' is to express it in a new (duplicate) question.

Not only reminded several times I should not post a new question, it still doesn't leave me with an alternative option. Catch-22.

The original question at hand was about "Should a person be required to leave a comment when down voting?" and my question can be found here:

*https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243608/down-voting-policy-what-is-the-communities-idea-on-this-feature*

The same question by another poster:

*[Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes?lq=1)*

Yes, I get that the question was asked before. I'll say it again another way (seeing as it's the only response anyone has given), I understand that I should not ask a duplicate question.

I think I make many valid arguments over the course of these comments and I think they all have been poorly addressed or better yet: not addressed at all.

In my opinion, Meta is the most useless of all Stack Exchange when it should be the opposite. I'm only expressing how I believe Meta could be better. It should be.

If anyone can actually post a real answer, it would be greatly appreciated.

**Below are the comments below if you don't want to navigate to the original post:
Note my comments and the actual responses. (Yes, I actually copy and pasted this to save it from the 'extended discussion' rule and 'comment trimming'.)**

> Downvotes mostly happens on questions that are not useful and don't
>   show research effort (because they have been asked before) –  rene 16
>   hours ago
>
> Maybe consider improving the search strings. I didn't see these posts
>   at all. Maybe then people wouldn't duplicate as many questions then.
>   :) –  David 16 hours ago
>
> Even if I visit the questions that are tagged down-votes I see
>   relevant posts. Maybe consider reading up on some faq's ;) –  rene 15
>   hours ago
>
> Maybe. But most posts I see here (on Meta) are down voted. It can't be
>   that everyone is because of a duplicate? If the question has been
>   asked many times then it must be a good idea. My question was down
>   voted but the same question was up voted over 550 times. How many
>   votes does it take for a policy to be made? –  David 15 hours ago
>
> @David This idea gets proposed several times a day and rejected
>   several times a day. The reason why they get downvoted is that
>   everyone is tired of seeing the same proposal over and over again and
>   also for the lack of research effort. Your best chance of getting this
>   policy implemented is to become majority shareholder of Stack
>   Exchange. –  Mysticial 15 hours ago
>
> The only people I really see down voting (on Meta) are the moderators.
>   So a good idea is down voted simply because it was asked previously?
>   Like the link in the first comment, upvoted. So are you down voting
>   the question itself or the policy? This is what I don't understand. –
>   David 15 hours ago
>
> Also, why have a voting policy if I have to be a shareholder? If we
>   are voting for features it doesn't make it very democratic. Don't get
>   me wrong, I like Stack Exchange but voting doesn't seem helpful in this
>   case either. –  David 15 hours ago
>
> @David You completely missed the point of my comment. I'm saying that
>   the policy you're proposing (mandatory comment for downvoting) has
>   been rejected by the company and will never be implemented. One way
>   you can get it implemented is to buy Stack Exchange. Then you can do
>   whatever you want with it. –  Mysticial 15 hours ago
>
> Now it sounds cleaner (still not democratic to the voters). Your
>   'reason' before was "everyone is tired of seeing the same proposal
>   over and over again and also the lack of research effort" Leaving me
>   to think it's just a sort of carelessness (on both parts). I don't
>   want to buy Stack Exchange, I don't like it that much. I missed the
>   point only because you failed to state the actual reason. I'll leave
>   it at that. Meta doesn't seem very interested in much anyway, in my
>   opinion. –  David 15 hours ago
>
> @David ordinary (non-moderating) members like me also downvote this
>   kind of request - as I have seen it many times over, heard the same
>   arguments over and over. It boils down to the fact that no one can
>   force anyone to write a coherent comment explaining the downvote. –
>   Sabre Tooth 10 hours ago
>
> -1, asdfghjkklaihwbdnmfowg –  Doorknob 1 hour ago
>
> Maybe I am failing to understand something. I get the fact that there
>   should technically be only one question/answer (it's more apparent in
>   other communities but often don't see the question down voted - only
>   merged/moved/held) I would think Meta is about the development of the
>   site and would less likely down vote something because it was simply
>   asked before. It doesn't have anything to do with the policy in
>   question. In fact, one post similar to mine has over 550 vote ups
>   (quite a number) and the fact that people are still 'many times over'
>   asking for it seems a good reason to consider it. –  David 1 hour ago
>
> and then there are snide/useless comments like doorknob's comment
>   which should be down voted but aren't. You can down vote a question on
>   the basis it was asked before and leave snide comments that can't be
>   down voted. I'm not sure how this leads to a learning environment in
>   this case. –  David 1 hour ago
>
> and also, I can't even vote up the original question because I don't
>   have enough rep. It only leaves me the option to ask a new question as
>   a way to cast my vote. –  David 1 hour ago

Comment: Already, less than 10 seconds after I post this I was down voted. Clearly not even enough time to actually read the post.

Comment: I see lots of waffle and little content.

Comment: Could you please format quoted sections as such. It's a pain to read this at the moment.

Comment: What needs to be formatted? It looks fine to me. I simple argument broken into paragraphs and a bold text to mark where comments begin.

Comment: So you have copy-pasted comments from a post we can actually still read. What is the point here?

Comment: The point is "comment trimming". I also stated, 'if you don't want to navigate.

Comment: "_I think I make many valid arguments over the course of these comments_" - don't spread your arguments all over comments, put them in your question from the start (showing that you have researched prior instances of that question).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what there is to answer here. At most this seems to be a rant about the reception of your other question and the fact that it is closed now. If that is indeed the case, don't waste your energy here, but put it into the other question so it can be reopened.

Comment: I'll leave it as this. It's actually amusing how many ways a person can avoid the actual question.

Comment: @David how would it be enforceable to stop a user posting something like `ddldglglglfdbg` just to fulfill a criteria to comment on downvoting?  Additionally, how would revenge-downvoting be prevented?

Comment: I don't think Meta is biased against new users. It _is_ generally biased against rants that come from people who are uninterested in the philosophy/history/culture of SE.

Comment: Maybe I am ranting NOW. @Sabre Tooth  - why are comments up-voted and not down-voted? What keeps them from posting dhdhdhd comments in any case? As far as revenge voting, its clearly a matter of personal issues and not related to learning at all.

Comment: It is a practicality to be considered.  Another thing to remember, it is the community members like me that vote up and down.  I choose to never explain downvotes on meta - as it is fairly well established that on meta, downvote = disagree.  If I may be blunt, if people do not like it, then too bad - the downvotes could be taken as being 'the community has spoken'.

Comment: Yes, I get that its your right to vote. I wouldn't take that from anyone. I still dont see a conclusive reason to down vote something purely on the basis: It was asked before. It doesn't have a bit to do with the policy in question (repeatedly) Isn't this why moderators have the option to hold/merge a question as it doesn't interfere with the policy vote.

Comment: I feel a bit like I am talking to a wall.

Comment: It does not matter if you see a conclusive reason, community members will continue to vote as they see fit.

Comment: and apparently without a valid reason. so what makes this different than revenge voting? as it doesn't pertain to the actual question.

Comment: it is impossible to control or to truly know people's voting intentions.  This topic has been discussed over and over and rejected as many times - in general, it would appear by the voting on this and other similar requests/discussions, that the community does not want it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)

Comment: "and apparently without a valid reason" is a **huge** assumption. It is also entirely unclear what constitutes a valid reason (or how we can agree on what that is).

Comment: "I still dont see a conclusive reason to down vote something purely on the basis: It was asked before." - I agree. I don't see a reason for that either - that's why we have close as duplicate as a close reason. I don't downvote stuff purely for being a duplicate. I _will_ downvote it due to lack of research, however. Which includes looking for duplicates.

Comment: I also like how the question is on hold because I am unclear? I asked a few direct questions. Revenge? Possibly. :)

Comment: You should re-read your post. It is unclear what you are seeking, what you are trying to get out of it (the questions seem like rhetoric rather than actual questions) - our format is rather specific - one question per post please. Straying away from that makes for difficult to answer questions.

Comment: Revenge? Who here would want revenge against you? And for what? And in the form of downvotes - I would say that's very ineffective revenge.

Comment: Which question do you find rhetorical? Should I point out the many double, triple, quadruple questions I've found on SE that deviate from the format? It can't be considered the standard even though it might be a request. Does it make more sense to write multiple related questions across the site or confine them to a single post?

Comment: It _is_ the standard - that you can find counter points means that you can find exceptions to the rule. The vast majority of questions are a single question - asking a bunch of question in one post can easily mean getting separate answers, one per each, or partial answers only addressing some and even not getting answers at all, as some people who would feel qualified to answer some will not be comfortable answering all of them. Also - I said _rhetoric_ not _rhetorical_ - these mean different things.

Comment: I read through it again and revised the question. Maybe this is easier to understand. You're right, it is the standard here but it can't be expected in all cases. So, youre eluding that a person should not answer unless he can give a quality answer to all questions? Will he be down-voted for not doing so? Not complying 100% to the SE 101 rulebook seems to result in that by the look of things.

Comment: People are free to answer as they wish. My point is that such a post is unlikely to get a response to each and every portion it is asking for an answer on. And that the answers that do come in may very much vary in quality. In short - it doesn't work well in our model. Nothing to do with a "rulebook" and as for downvotes - people are free to vote as they wish (it is a fundamental of the sites), but anecdotally, that doesn't happen - if anything, such a question - a few in one, is what gets downvoted.

Comment: I see your edits, but if anything, they've only gone more abstract and murky. I really don't get what you are trying to say and what you wish to discuss anymore. I don't know what "policy/feature" pertains to. Please try to be clear and avoid being circumspect.

Comment: ? What is the purpose of Meta? In my understanding, it is a place to vote for a policy or feature we want or don't want. What I see is voting if a question complies with the rules of SE or not. Where should I direct my requests to if this is not the correct community?

Comment: Please avoid extended discussions in comments? Is this not tagged as 'discussion'?

Comment: @David `Please avoid extended discussions in comments` is an automatic feature across SE - discussions like this are generally discouraged (we are not a forum) - but issues can chatted about in a chat room

Answer (score 17):

> How is this logic of moderation condusive to a growing learning environment?

Ah. I think I see where you are going wrong. It is in this bit: "a growing learning environment".

That's not what Stack Exchange is about. It is about building a compendium of great questions and answers - questions about *specific* issues and answers to them.

It is **not** a learning environment. It never was. If it were, you would see tutorials, recommendations and more here. You don't see them as what we are looking for is not to educate people - it is to give them direct answers to their specific questions.

---

There is also a certain naive notion there that in a learning environment moderation is not required - of course it is. In a school, disruptive students are sent to the head teacher, do they not? And if you tell me that learning environments don't have disruptive people, you must have been in different ones than I.

---

I will not rehash the reasons for why we don't require downvoters to explain themselves (unless you ask me to).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. First real answer that attempts to help me understand SE. I agree there is always disruptiveness in any situation (beyond SE and learning environments) Even to say that SE is not a learning environment is 'reaching' a bit though. If for the sake of learning how to fix a specific problem, you've learned something (in atleast the sense of how to fix it.) But, I do appreciate the effort and time. I would up vote this provided I could.

Comment: @David - that people do learn from answers here doesn't make the site a learning environment. You are conflating "I learnt something from this" with "This is a place for learning".